# How to Remove Excess WhiteSpace or Paragraph from Pre Tag

Tags: html, css

The pre tag is used for defining block of preformatted text in order to preserve the tab, text space, line break e.t.c.

But I don't really know while this is not working for me. Am having excess WhiteSpace in all my blog posts.

I have provided a screenshot for view as well as a live url to see the effect of what am trying to explained.

I tried this:

```
.pre-blog{white-space:pre-line;white-space:-moz-pre-line;white-space:-pre-line;white-space:-o-pre-line;word-wrap:break-word;word-break:keep-all;line-height:1.5em; display:inline;margin:0}
```

But no luck with it cos it couldn't solve the issue.

[Here](https://www.emmason247.com.ng/blog/what-is-ram-and-its-types--advantages-and-disadvantages-of-ram/VZDDGIDGbD/GbGVCICVGD) is one of the blog posts that you can access and see what I am trying to explain.

Screenshot:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

the whitespace you show in the screenshot is the space between li items. This is default styling applied for these html elements.

Easiest way to get rid of the space would be to apply display: flex and flex-direction: column to the parent, which is the ol element

[image: applied display flex with flex-direction column to ol element]

Comment: Your answer came in as I was typing mine :P kudos on figuring out and fixing the whitespace problem!

Comment: Thanks for the list items solution. It worked perfectly. How about the other excess WhiteSpace, any idea on how to override them?

Comment: @user14211563 can you be more specific which whitespace in which place you mean? Then I can check in that place

Comment: Like the space between 3. It has limited storage capacity and the Characteristics of Primary Memory is too much

Comment: both ol and with list items and the h2 under it have margin applied to. If you add margin: 0 to both of them it would be ok. 

However the more structural solution would be to add a css reset to your global css file so you don't have to undo the default applied styles every time

for example like described in this blogpost

https://www.joshwcomeau.com/css/custom-css-reset/

The most important for you is to add

* {
  margin: 0;
}

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be trying to put `<div>`s and other elements inside the `<pre>`. As far as I know that's not how `<pre>` works; it's only meant to contain plaintext that you want preformatted in a certain way [as described here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_pre.asp). It's usually used for displaying things like computer code that need all their indentation preserved.

Your screenshot and linked web page seem to be ordinary formatted text. I'm not sure what exactly you're trying to achieve, but `<pre>` is not the right way to do it; you'll have better luck with proper use of `<p>` and `<br>` tags and CSS styling with properties like `margin`, `padding`, and `line-height`. (Depending on your use-case, if you want to avoid manually typing tags, you might want to consider something like [Markdown](https://www.markdownguide.org/) to automatically add the formatting tags for you).

I suggest you replace your `<pre>` with a `<div>`, and then post a different question regarding the whitespace if you're not able to figure it out yourself.

Comment: Yes. The pre tag contains other tags like h2, list items e.t.c. I tried using div initially but did get the results I wanted and therefore decided to use pre tag